# How many minimum constraints are required for one UI object ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, constraints

Most of the interviews common question is "How many minimum constraints are required for one UI object" Can someone please clarify?

Comment: For objects with intrinsic contentsize, usually 2 - one horizontal and one vertical. Otherwise you would need to specify width and height as well or one each of the other horizontal and vertical constraints.

Comment: UIStackView + intrinsicSize, technically it can be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what are the constraints (how would you determine the appropriate constraints), basically, the minimum required constraints are the constraints that should determine the *size* and the *origin* of the component (`height`, `width`, `x` and `y`).

Keep in mind it is *not* only required to specify each property by its own literal  constraint, for example, you could determine what is the width of the component by setting *leading* and *trailing* constraints to it instead of equals constant width. Furthermore, components with *intrinsic content size* should not have always fixed size (height and width), hence determining their origins (x and y) would be sufficient, unless there is a need to setup their constants.

Answer (score 0):

To be short, excluding the case of an `UIScrollView` where the content size is involved as well, you need 2 distinct constraints per axis (horizontal and vertical).
It's also important to note that if an UI element has an intrinsic size, that counts as a constraint for that axis already, even though it can be overridden with constraints that have higher priority.